# Cannot load Zend Extension Manager (CentOS 5)

Tags: php, ssh, kloxo

On Installed Kloxo 6.12, I Upgraded PHP,

When run php --ini 
It is the output:

> [root@server1 /]# php --ini

Cannot load Zend Extension Manager - it was built with configuration 1.2.0, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS

> lxphp.exe -v

PHP 5.3.28 (cli) (built: Feb  3 2014 00:20:35)
Copyright (c) 1997-2013 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2013 Zend Technologies

> php -v

Cannot load Zend Extension Manager - it was built with configuration 1.2.0, whereas running engine is API220100525,NTS

--

and php.ini content in /etc/php.ini is:

```
; Added by Kloxo file/phpini/php.ini.temp
;--- 
register_globals = off
display_errors = off
file_uploads = on

upload_max_filesize = 2M
log_errors = off
output_buffering = off
register_argc_argv = on
magic_quotes_gpc  = off 
post_max_size = 8M
magic_quotes_runtime = off
magic_quotes_sybase = off
mysql.allow_persistent = off
max_execution_time = 30
max_input_time = 60
memory_limit = 32M
allow_url_fopen = on
allow_url_include = on
register_long_arrays = on
session.save_path = /var/lib/php/session
cgi.force_redirect = on
; sendmail_from = 
safe_mode = off
enable_dl = on
disable_functions = exec,passthru,shell_exec,system,proc_open,popen,curl_exec,curl_multi_exec,show_source
zlib.output_compression = off
;
; xcache

;
; ioncube loader
;zend_extension=/usr/lib/kloxophp/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_age.so
;
; zend engine loader/optimizer 
[Zend]
zend_extension=/usr/lib/php/modules/ioncube/ioncube_loader_lin_5.4.so
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer=/usr/lib/kloxophp/zend/lib/Optimizer-3.2.8
;zend_extension_manager.optimizer_ts=/usr/lib/kloxophp/zend/lib/Optimizer_TS-3.2.8
zend_optimizer.version=3.2.8
zend_extension=/usr/lib/kloxophp/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager.so
zend_extension_ts=/usr/lib/kloxophp/zend/lib/ZendExtensionManager_TS.so

;---
; Added by Kloxo file/phpini/php.ini.temp
;---
```

what's the Problem?